# If a new Promise is inside exterior function where are .then() .catch() added?

Tags: javascript, promise

In the code below the function, readFileAsync() is used to read a file and return a new Promise.  It doesn't throw an error but it may not be structured properly.

```
function readFileAsync(filename) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile((path.join(__dirname, filename)), { encoding: 'utf-8' }, (err, data) => {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}

console.log(readFileAsync('/helperData/jsonFormat.txt'));
```

**Question**: How do I structure this example to use `.then()` and `.catch()`? No matter where I locate these (inside or outside the function) it throws an exception.  I feel like I might have coded myself into a corner and I'm not sure how this pattern needs to be laid out.

Comment: Your `readFileAsync` is right - it returns a Promise when called, so to get the resolved value, call `.then` on its call (and to catch errors, call `.catch` on its call) eg `readFileAsync(...).then(console.log).catch((err) => /* handle err */)`

Comment: Oh, one thing, change `reject(Error, err);` to `reject(err)`

Comment: Thanks CertainPerformance, I've tried that pattern but it also throws an exception.  `ReferenceError: data is not defined`,  `readFileAsync('/helperData/jsonFormat.txt').then( console.log(data) ).catch();`

Comment: instead of function declaration, try : `var readFileAsync = new Promise(....) ` Then you can do `readFileAsync.then()`

Comment: @MichelleDai The function form is a *lot* more flexible than just declaring a Promise, though

Comment: `.then` accepts a *function* as a parameter, not plain code lines - either `.then(console.log)` or `.then((data) => console.log(data))`

Comment: @CertainPerformance how about instead of function declaration, try function expression for `var readFileAsync = .... function that will return a Promise`. Then `readFileAsync.then()` and `.catch()` after that block code

Comment: @techieWannabe Function declaration vs expression makes no difference in this case. Since `readFileAsync` will be a function, have to call it, not just reference it, to get a Promise from it - `readFileAsync(...).then(...`, not just `readFileAsync.then(...`

Comment: I just wanted to say I've ready through all these comments and I've got it working.  Understanding that I was passing a function to .then() and not just a simple parameter makes it all make sense.  Thanks!